# mysql set a string value to a whole column

Tags: mysql, string, set

My table name is `tostategrouping`, and I have a column with name `toState`.

I put the table into the database of "test" in `mysql`.

I want to set the word "NY" to the column `toState`.

The rest of the code is to select data with some conditions, which you can ignore.

There is always error running the code and the problem shows be at the `update ...set...value=` part.

However, this script is exactly the same with everyone talking about about the function.

Assistance is required.

```
SELECT ttUserID,
       screenName,
       name,
       max(statusCount)AS statusCount,
       max(followers)AS followersCount,
       max(followings)AS followingsCount,
       ttCountAbtMoving,
       toState,
       interestedTopic,
       importanceToTgting,
       ttPost
FROM test.tostategrouping
WHERE ttPost LIKE "%mov%new%york%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov% ny %"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%brooklyn%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%queens%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%manhattan%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%staten%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%island%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%buffalo%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%long island%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%rochester%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%the hamptons%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%bronx%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%syracuse%"
  OR ttPost LIKE"%mov%ithaca%"
  OR ttPost LIKE"%mov%yonkers%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%new%york%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr% ny %"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%brooklyn%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%queens%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%manhattan%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%staten%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%island%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%buffalo%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%long island%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%rochester%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%the hamptons%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%bronx%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%syracuse%"
  OR ttPost LIKE"%transferr%ithaca%"
  OR ttPost LIKE"%transferr%yonkers%"
GROUP BY ttUserID
UPDATE test.tostategrouping
SET tostategrouping_toState=1;
```

Comment: You're trying to make an "update" inside an "select" that's not possible that way.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you're trying to execute two different types of queries (SELECT and UPDATE) in one, which you cannot do. Try something this:

```
UPDATE test.tostategrouping
SET tostategrouping_toState=1
WHERE ttUserID IN
    (SELECT ttUserID,
       screenName,
       name,
       max(statusCount)AS statusCount,
       max(followers)AS followersCount,
       max(followings)AS followingsCount,
       ttCountAbtMoving,
       toState,
       interestedTopic,
       importanceToTgting,
       ttPost
FROM test.tostategrouping
WHERE ttPost LIKE "%mov%new%york%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov% ny %"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%brooklyn%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%queens%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%manhattan%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%staten%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%island%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%buffalo%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%long island%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%rochester%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%the hamptons%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%bronx%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%mov%syracuse%"
  OR ttPost LIKE"%mov%ithaca%"
  OR ttPost LIKE"%mov%yonkers%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%new%york%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr% ny %"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%brooklyn%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%queens%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%manhattan%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%staten%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%island%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%buffalo%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%long island%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%rochester%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%the hamptons%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%bronx%"
  OR ttPost LIKE "%transferr%syracuse%"
  OR ttPost LIKE"%transferr%ithaca%"
  OR ttPost LIKE"%transferr%yonkers%"
GROUP BY ttUserID);
```

This restricts your update to only change rows that are selected by the subquery.

Comment: hi i guess it should have worked, but it returned me with error box saying "Operand should contain 1 column(s)". don't know why

Comment: Please set up a sample with some demo data in a new fiddle on [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so that we can help you more effectively.

Comment: hi i dont not how to use fiddle, but i sent the data to your email hello...@.. would you please check it there?